# Android - Exception using main thread and posting data to PHP

Tags: java, php, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

When I run my android app and activate a click event that tries to transfer data from a table row to post it to a PHP file, the main thread forces the app to shut-down regardless of using another thread in the background to establish the network connection (using AsyncTask). Below I have provided my files:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.stevenkennedy.categorizer;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Local Variables
private Boolean snapBool = false;
private Boolean snapBool2 = false;
private Boolean snapBool3 = false;
private Boolean snapBool4 = false;
private Boolean snapBool5 = false;

// Add ImageView objects for camera
private ImageView snap;
private ImageView snap2;
private ImageView snap3;
private ImageView snap4;
private ImageView snap5;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;

// Add Button for click event for server communication
private Button sendBtn;

// Row 1
private EditText idRow1;
private EditText nameRow1;
private Spinner categoryRow1;
private EditText commentRow1;
private EditText priceRow1;
private ImageView galleryRow1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Row 1
    idRow1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idBox);
    nameRow1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameBox);
    categoryRow1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cateBox);
    commentRow1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.commBox);
    priceRow1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.priceBox);
    galleryRow1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gallBox);


    // listeners for camera event
    snap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gallBox);
    snap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            // flag local boolean
            snapBool = true;
        }

    });

   snap2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gallBox2);
    snap2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            // flag local boolean
            snapBool2 = true;
        }

    });

    snap3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gallBox3);
    snap3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            // flag local boolean
            snapBool3 = true;
        }

    });

    snap4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gallBox4);
    snap4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            // flag local boolean
            snapBool4 = true;
        }

    });

    snap5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gallBox5);
    snap5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            // flag local boolean
            snapBool5 = true;
        }

    });

    // confirm button to send data to server
    sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // create AsyncTask to get user entered cell data
        new MyTask().execute();

    }

});





} // ******** ON CREATE END ************

/*
* Method that activates the camera and gets a thumbnail of the photo for the
* table cell
 */
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

       if (snapBool == true) {
           snap.setImageBitmap(photo);
       } else if (snapBool2 == true) {
           snap2.setImageBitmap(photo);
       } else if (snapBool3 == true) {
           snap3.setImageBitmap(photo);
       } else if (snapBool4 == true) {
           snap4.setImageBitmap(photo);
       } else if(snapBool5 == true) {
           snap5.setImageBitmap(photo);
       }

        // set boolean flags back to false
        snapBool = false;
        snapBool2 = false;
        snapBool3 = false;
        snapBool4 = false;
        snapBool5 = false;
    }
}

/*
 * Method to get cell data of Row 1 and send it to a sql server using
 * post data with php
 */
public void getCells() {

        // get the data in boxes
        String str1 = idRow1.getText().toString();
        String str2 = nameRow1.getText().toString();
        String str3 = categoryRow1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String str4 = commentRow1.getText().toString();
        String str5 = priceRow1.getText().toString();
        //galleryRow1.get

        // create sql object
        MySQLConnect sql = new MySQLConnect(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, "png23.png");
        sql.sendTo();
}


/**
 * AsyncTask Class
 */
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        getCells();

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {}

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}


} // ************** CLASS END **************
```

**MySQLConnect.java**

```
package com.example.stevenkennedy.categorizer;

import android.media.Image;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;


/**
 * Created by Steven Kennedy on 27/10/2015.
 */
public class MySQLConnect {

// Class Variables
private String id;
private String name;
private String cate;
private String comm;
private String price;
private String gall;

// constructor
public MySQLConnect(String id, String name, String cate, String comm, String price, String gall){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.cate = cate;
    this.comm = comm;
    this.price = price;
    this.gall = gall;
}

// getters and setters
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCate() {
    return cate;
}

public void setCate(String cate) {
    this.cate = cate;
}

public String getComm() {
    return comm;
}

public void setComm(String comm) {
    this.comm = comm;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getGall() {
    return gall;
}

public void setGall(String gall) {
    this.gall = gall;
}

public void sendTo() {

    // HTTP client
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // use php to post data to
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://myPHPfile.com/myFile.php");

    try {
        // add to arraylist
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        // add values
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", this.getId() ));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", this.getName()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", this.getCate()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", this.getComm()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", this.getPrice()));
        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gallery", this.getGall()));

        // send to server - POST
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        client.execute(post);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException ed) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ed.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



} // ********* END ***********
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Header Table -->
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/topTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:background="#B3EAFF">

    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTitle"
            android:text="id"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="70dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="Name"
            android:paddingRight="75dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="Category"
            android:paddingRight="55dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Comment"
            android:paddingRight="45dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Price"
            android:paddingRight="30dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Gallery" />
    </TableRow>
    <!-- drawn line -->
    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090" />
</TableLayout>

<!-- Scroll Layout -->
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topTable"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:id="@+id/idBox" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:id="@+id/nameBox"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idBox"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/idBox" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:entries="@array/cate_array"
        android:prompt="@string/cate_spin"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nameBox"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nameBox"
        android:id="@+id/cateBox" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cateBox"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cateBox"
        android:id="@+id/commBox" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:digits="0123456789."
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/commBox"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/commBox"
        android:id="@+id/priceBox" />
    <!--<EditText
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:onClick="true"
        android:text="   [  O  ]"
        android:editable="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/priceBox"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/priceBox"
        android:id="@+id/gallBox" />-->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:onClick="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/priceBox"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/priceBox"
        android:id="@+id/gallBox"/>

    <!-- Row 2 -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/idBox"
        android:id="@+id/idBox2" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:id="@+id/nameBox2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameBox"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idBox2" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:entries="@array/cate_array"
        android:prompt="@string/cate_spin"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nameBox2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cateBox"
        android:id="@+id/cateBox2" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cateBox2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/commBox"
        android:id="@+id/commBox2" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:digits="0123456789."
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/commBox2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/priceBox"
        android:id="@+id/priceBox2" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:onClick="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/priceBox2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gallBox"
        android:id="@+id/gallBox2"/>

    <!-- Row 3 -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/idBox2"
        android:id="@+id/idBox3" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:id="@+id/nameBox3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameBox2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idBox3" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:entries="@array/cate_array"
        android:prompt="@string/cate_spin"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nameBox3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cateBox2"
        android:id="@+id/cateBox3" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cateBox3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/commBox2"
        android:id="@+id/commBox3" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:digits="0123456789."
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/commBox3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/priceBox2"
        android:id="@+id/priceBox3" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:onClick="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/priceBox3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gallBox2"
        android:id="@+id/gallBox3"/>

    <!-- Row 4 -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/idBox3"
        android:id="@+id/idBox4" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:id="@+id/nameBox4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameBox3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idBox4" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:entries="@array/cate_array"
        android:prompt="@string/cate_spin"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nameBox4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cateBox3"
        android:id="@+id/cateBox4" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cateBox4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/commBox3"
        android:id="@+id/commBox4" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:digits="0123456789."
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/commBox4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/priceBox3"
        android:id="@+id/priceBox4" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:onClick="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/priceBox4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gallBox3"
        android:id="@+id/gallBox4"/>

    <!-- Row 5 -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/idBox4"
        android:id="@+id/idBox5" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:id="@+id/nameBox5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameBox4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idBox5" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:entries="@array/cate_array"
        android:prompt="@string/cate_spin"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nameBox5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cateBox4"
        android:id="@+id/cateBox5" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cateBox5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/commBox4"
        android:id="@+id/commBox5" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:digits="0123456789."
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/commBox5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/priceBox4"
        android:id="@+id/priceBox5" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:onClick="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/priceBox5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gallBox4"
        android:id="@+id/gallBox5"/>

    <!-- Send to server -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_below="@+id/idBox5"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**myFile.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "******";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";

// POST data
$idPass = $_POST['id'];
$namePass = $_POST['name'];
$catePass = $_POST['category'];
$commPass = $_POST['comment];
$pricePass = $_POST['price'];
//$gallPass = $_POST['gallery'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO viewer VALUES ('$idPass', '$namePass', '$catePass', '$commPass', '$pricePass', 'imge.png')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

---

If anyone knows a better way to connect to a database that doesn't require a lot of memory usage, I would gladly take that as an answer. I also know about Apache libraries being depreciated as of the latest updates, and have tried the java HttpURLConnection class to post data, but got the same issue of the main thread exception.

Comment: Please post your exception's full stack trace.

Comment: Add your LogCat output so we have an idea of where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are getting an exception like: "Method getText() must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker."

You cannot use the View#getText() from the background Thread in your AsyncTask.

What you need to do is to pass your Strings on your execute method changing the signature in:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
```

Answer (score 0):

No. you just need to add :

new `THread(new Runable(){on Run()}).start()` to wrap up your code for request!

```
public void sendTo() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // HTTP client 
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // use php to post data to 
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://myPHPfile.com/myFile.php");

                try {
                    // add to arraylist 
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    // add values 
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", this.getId() ));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", this.getName()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", this.getCate()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", this.getComm()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", this.getPrice()));
                    //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gallery", this.getGall())); 

                    // send to server - POST 
                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    //HttpResponse response = client.execute(post); 
                    client.execute(post);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException ed) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                    ed.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
```